Firebase Cloud Messaging problems
I wanted to add notifications to my app but I get this error in console:

A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
index.esm2017.js:843 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8080/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:8080/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
    at registerDefaultSw (index.esm2017.js:843:29)
    at async updateSwReg (index.esm2017.js:867:9)
    at async getToken$1 (index.esm2017.js:930:5)

here is App.vue file:
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import { useUserStore } from "stores/userStore";
import './firebase-cloud-messging-sw'

const userStore = useUserStore();

onMounted(() => {
  userStore.firebaseAuthStateChanged();
});
</script>

firebase-cloud-messging-sw.js file:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
   // api keys
};

function requestPermission() {
    console.log("Requesting permission...");
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
        if (permission === "granted") {
            console.log("Notification permission granted.");
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

            const messaging = getMessaging(app);
            getToken(messaging, {
                vapidKey:
                    "my vapid key",
            }).then((currentToken) => {
                if (currentToken) {
                    console.log("currentToken: ", currentToken);
                } else {
                    console.log("Can not get token");
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Do not have permission!");
        }
    });
}

requestPermission();

Both files are in the same directory
I read that this error means I need to move firebase-cloud-messging-sw.js file to the root directory, but I moved the file to another location but the results were still the same.
Any ideas where the problem is?
